# Finding the difference between 2 dates in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm wondering if there's a way to compare two dates in Swift. I'm using dates to keep track of my timer when the app goes into the background, and also to track when people use a certain feature of my app. I'm currently using two `Date()` variables and use math to compare the two `calendar.DateComponents()` of the two dates. I'm sure Swift must have an easier way to get the difference between two `DateComponents`, but I don't know how to do this. I would like to get the difference between the two dates in seconds. I'm using XCode 11.4, Swift 5. Thanks!

Comment: Look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2292887-datecomponents or https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293176-datecomponents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `DateComponents` then. `Date` has a `distance(to:)` method that returns the difference in seconds:

```
let diff = someDate.distance(to: anotherDate)
```

Comment: Not just "you don't need DateComponents" but "you absolutely stay away from DateComponents". Unless you have a really thorough understanding of what you need.